# What is wrong about installation of fabric-chaintool?

Tags: macos, hyperledger

I am installing https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaintool on Macbook.

The error pop up in process of "make install".

Is the target/chaintool in the directory of "/Users/Will/Documents/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/fabric-chaintool/target/base+system+user+dev/chaintool" ?

Really thanks in advance on help。

```
Copying binary to target
cp target/chaintool /usr/bin
cp: /usr/bin/chaintool: Operation not permitted
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

When I test chaincode (Golang coding program), I will use CLI. It seems this chaintool can help us to test chaincode on RESTful service. 
If so, it will help to make web RESTful call easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem because "System Integrity Protection" is enabled on your mac.

The solution is described here [Operation Not Permitted when on root El capitan (rootless disabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled)

As a workaround you can update `Makefile` file and copy chaintool into another folder, or disable "System Integrity Protection" using:

```
reboot with CMD+R, open the terminal and run "csrutil disable"
reboot 
...
make install
...
reboot with CMD+R again, open the terminal and run  "csrutil enable"
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix your command with 'sudo'

sudo cp target/chaintool /usr/bin