# libsystem_symptoms.dylib missing in Xcode 8

Tags: xml, xcode, macos

I just updated to Xcode 8, and I can no longer build xml2-based applications.  If I build a simple file and try to build it as follows:

```
c++ myapp.cc `xml2-config --cflags` `xml2-config --libs`
```

...I get the following error message:

```
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib for architecture x86_64
```

It doesn't matter what's in myapp.cc (mine is just a main routine that returns 0).  The root problem seems to be that Apple removed /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib in Xcode 8, but many of the .tbd files in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib still point to it.  Has anyone else run into a problem like this?

Comment: I did a temp fix of symlinking  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib to /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib and it looks like this allows the builds to work. It's not a right solution of course but a temp fix that will enable to build stuff until the real fix arrives. You'd need to disable SIP before (there's a lot of info online on how to do it).

Answer (score 15):

@mnencia answer works removing references to libsystem_symptomps.dylib, but failed for me using OS X.  Change the following should allow it to work on OS X:

```
sudo /usr/bin/sed -i.backup -E -e 's@/usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib(, )?@@' \
$(grep -ril /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib \
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib)
```

Hope this helps Mac developers.

Answer (score 3):

This is an XCode 8 bug.

While waiting for a proper fix from Apple, the following command removes the reference to the missing library from the tbd files.

```
sudo /usr/bin/sed -i.backup 's@/usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib\(, \)\?@@' \
  $(grep -ril /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib \
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib)
```

I don't know if it will works for every kind of build, but it fixed everything was not working for me.

Comment: I tried this and go the following errors: grep:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib: No such file or directory
sed:  : No such file or directory.  Any thoughts?  The /usr/lib directory does exist (im running the same version of macOS)

Comment: maybe the sdk path is different.  Try searching for .tbd files inside the /Applications/Xcode.app folder.

Comment: This found all the right files, but the replace didn't work - the backup files were the same as the changed files.

Comment: If you run it twice, the 2nd backup will clobber the first one. If the backup doesn't contain any reference to `/usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib` that's probably what happened.

Comment: Does this bug have a radar?

Answer (score 3):

Until Xcode8 stabilizes, I retain Xcode7.3, renamed as

`/Applications/Xcode7.3.app/`

Generally I use Xcode8 which is in

`/Applications/Xcode.app/`

but when encountering errors such as this, I have the option to

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode7.3.app/`

This cured the error

`ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib for architecture x86_64`

for me, when attempting to install an R package:

`> install.packages('clickstream')`

Answer (score 2):

One "fix" that I've used, which avoids any use of sudo, is simply to filter out the -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib flag.  In a GNU makefile, this can be done with the filter-out command.  So if I build a LINK_LIBS variable, which includes $(shell xml2-config --libs), then I can filter LINK_LIBS with the following command:

```
LINK_LIBS := $(filter-out -L$(shell xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/lib, $(LINK_LIBS))
```

If I'm just using xml2-config, I can also just add a "--exec-prefix=/usr" argument when calling it:

```
c++ myapp.cc `xml2-config --cflags` `xml2-config --exec-prefix=/usr --libs`
```

I don't know what potential side effects of removing the SDK path from the library search string might be, but for now, these solutions seem to work for all of my applications.

Answer (score 1):

@mnencia's answer *almost* worked for me, but the sed command didn't replace anything in the TLB files - the backups were the same as the modified files.

I ran this part of his command:

`grep -ril /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib`

Which identified the files referencing the removed library and modified them by hand.

**YMMV**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone uncomfortable with stripping out references to `libsystem_symptoms.dylib` from various locations, I came up with another solution that's the opposite of removing references -- adding a fake empty `libsystem_symptoms.dylib` in `/usr/lib/system`!

```
mkdir ~/src/libempty
cd ~/src/libempty
touch empty.c
cc -dynamiclib empty.c -o libempty.dylib
sudo cp libempty.dylib /usr/local/lib/libempty.dylib
cd /usr/lib/system
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libempty.dylib libsystem_symptoms.dylib
```

Except... that last step doesn't work because of OS X/macOS [System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html).

There's apparently more than one way of getting around that; you can disable it using `csrutil` and rebooting (see the question [Operation Not Permitted when on root El capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled)). I don't really want to disable it (or forget to turn it back on), so I booted into [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314), and then opened a terminal window and finished the job this way:

```
cd /Volumes
cd MyHardDrive
cd usr/lib/system
ln -s ../../local/lib/libempty.dylib libsystem_symptoms.dylib
```

Before doing this, I was trying to build PostgreSQL 9.6 on El Capitan, and was getting that linker error (`"ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib"`) at the `configure` step when it checked for the readline or zlib libraries. After doing this, PostgreSQL configured and built smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

The final update from geoHeil on https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/173 helped me resolve this issue on OSX.

It was as simple as these two steps:

```
Terminal> brew uninstall suite-sparse --ignore-dependencies
R> install.packages("igraph")
```

`ignore-dependencies` was necessary because Octave had a dependency on suite-sparse.