# Error installing Nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder Mac El Capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### get this error when doing bundle install:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder (0.9.3pre), and
Bundler cannot continue.
```

---

### I've tried all the different suggestions for installing nokigori but none worked so I tried:

```
gem install nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder

Fetching: nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder-0.9.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/sylviaalowden/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder-0.9.2/ext/nokogiri_ext_xmlsec
/Users/sylviaalowden/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160921-62548-1ly6yoh.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby.h... yes
Clfags: $(cflags)  -fno-common -pipe -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\" -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_SIZE_T -DXMLSEC_NO_GOST=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -DXMLSEC_OPENSSL_100=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_OPENSSL=1 -fvisibility=hidden
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/sylviaalowden/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0/nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder-0.9.2/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/sylviaalowden/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder-0.9.2/ext/nokogiri_ext_xmlsec
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/sylviaalowden/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder-0.9.2/ext/nokogiri_ext_xmlsec
make "DESTDIR="
compiling init.c
In file included from init.c:1:
In file included from ./xmlsecrb.h:19:
/usr/local/Cellar/libxmlsec1/1.2.20_1/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/templates.h:11:9: warning: '__XMLSEC_TEMPLATES_H__' is used as a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro [-Wheader-guard]
#ifndef __XMLSEC_TEMPLATES_H__
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/libxmlsec1/1.2.20_1/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/templates.h:12:9: note: '__XMLSEC_TEMPALTES_H__' is defined here; did you mean '__XMLSEC_TEMPLATES_H__'?
#define __XMLSEC_TEMPALTES_H__
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        __XMLSEC_TEMPLATES_H__
1 warning generated.
compiling nokogiri_decrypt_with_key.c
In file included from nokogiri_decrypt_with_key.c:1:
In file included from ./xmlsecrb.h:19:
/usr/local/Cellar/libxmlsec1/1.2.20_1/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/templates.h:11:9: warning: '__XMLSEC_TEMPLATES_H__' is used as a header guard here, 
........................
/usr/local/Cellar/libxmlsec1/1.2.20_1/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/templates.h:12:9: note: '__XMLSEC_TEMPALTES_H__' is defined here; did you mean '__XMLSEC_TEMPLATES_H__'?
#define __XMLSEC_TEMPALTES_H__
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        __XMLSEC_TEMPLATES_H__
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object nokogiri_ext_xmlsec.bundle
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [nokogiri_ext_xmlsec.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Only showing beginning and end of mkmf.log for space reasons. How can I fix this?

Comment: Any luck getting this to install?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on EL Capitan and my fix was to:

`brew install libxmlsec1`

after which `bundle install` worked.

Comment: I found this worked with `nokogiri-xmlsec`, but there was more to do with `nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder` (as per @Kulgar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39729692/1157242), which was more work than it was worth for me).

Answer (score 1):

I faced it myself and this one isn't easy.

First there is a typo in  /usr/local/Cellar/libxmlsec1/1.2.20_1/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/templates.h

Line 12, you have to replace `__XMLSEC_TEMPALTES_H__`by `__XMLSEC_TEMPLATES_H__`

I then faced another issue (I think due to a XCode 8 bug...): 
`ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib for architecture x86_64`

I found this answer: [libsystem_symptoms.dylib missing in Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536144/libsystem-symptoms-dylib-missing-in-xcode-8/39611855)

But the first solution cannot be used here and the second one didn't work. So I went to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib` and performed my own sed:

`grep -irl /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib * | xargs sudo /usr/bin/sed -i.backup -e"s/\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_symptoms.dylib, / /"`

This command will create backup files (with .backup extension) for each modified file in case something goes wrong.

Only then nokogiri-xmlsec-me-harder could be installed.