# point knitr to bash 4 on mac

Tags: r, bash, macos, rstudio, knitr

I have updated my bash to bash version 4.4.0 on mac osx. However, as explained in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx), I cannot update the bash version under `bin/bash` but just install a parallel shell under `/usr/local/bin/bash`

how can I point knitr to this shell? `engine.path` seems to get ignored:

````
```{r, engine='bash', engine.path='/usr/local/bin/bash'}
which bash
```
````

gives

> /bin/bash

**update**

@ Kevin: yes you are right, `echo $BASH` gives `/usr/local/bin/bash`

BUT:

*from knitr*

````
```{bash, engine.path='/usr/local/bin/bash'}
which bash
echo $BASH
bash --version
```
````

gives

> /bin/bash
>
> /usr/local/bin/bash
>
> GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
>   Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

*while the same from the command line gives*

[image]

**edit 2**

after re-reading the answer of @Kevin, *this works*

````
```{r, engine = "bash", engine.path = "/usr/local/bin/bash"}
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

bash --version
```
````

> GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)

Answer (score 1):

What does `echo $BASH` print? It's possible that your `PATH` has `/usr/bin` before `/usr/local/bin`, or even `/usr/local/bin` is not on the `PATH`.

For example, I see:

[image]

indicating that `engine.path` is indeed being respected.

Comment: If I give an uncomplete path, I get an error message which reads ```/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/: is a directory```. Could it be that knitr used some version of ```#!bin/sh``` which calls sh, not bash? And that sh is a symlink to the system bash as suggested in this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash? However under el Capitan it is not longer (easily) possible to change links in 'rootless' mode (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled)