# chown: changing ownership of '/u01/app/oracle': Operation not permitted

Tags: oracle, macos, docker

I am using Docker (Community edition, Version 17.09.1-ce-mac42 (21090), 3176a6af01). For webapp development, I need Oracle 12c (and I need saving my works (database table, view, data, etc.) after close Docker application), therefore I use https://github.com/MaksymBilenko/docker-oracle-12c

I do these steps

```
sudo docker pull sath89/oracle-12c
sudo mkdir -p /Users/donhuvy/Documents/oracle12c_data
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 -v /Users/donhuvy/Documents/oracle12c_data:/u01/app/oracle -e DBCA_TOTAL_MEMORY=2048 sath89/oracle-12c
```

Result

```
eccdc90353d36e85f08597dea894da332a29024d88c3e80d20894540029667d4
```

then

```
docker logs -f eccdc90353d36e85f08597dea894da332a29024d88c3e80d20894540029667d4
```

I see this error:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/u01/app/oracle': Operation not permitted
```

[image]

What is the cause and how to avoid the error?

Comment: Why `close(1)`?

Comment: Does any of the following work: 1. Try running the container without the `-v` option. 2. Try starting the container with `-v` option and `--user root`

Comment: When I run `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 /Users/donhuvy/Documents/oracle12c_data:/u01/app/oracle -e DBCA_TOTAL_MEMORY=2048 sath89/oracle-12c` I see `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: Remove `/Users/donhuvy/Documents/oracle12c_data:/u01/app/oracle` this is the value of `-v` option.

Comment: When I run `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521  -e DBCA_TOTAL_MEMORY=2048 sath89/oracle-12c` It works, but I need few minutes to test saving my works (create database, turn off Docker, re-open, and check existing my works). Seemly, your comment is not ultimate solution. I need saving my works in Docker images/container after close Docker. I can run it success, but I want save my job after close Docker.

Comment: @yamenk , I must save data after work. Without option `-v`, when I close Docker, I can't save database schema, data what I created. Let's see user manual: https://github.com/MaksymBilenko/docker-oracle-12c#installation section ***Run with data on host and reuse it***

Comment: Looks like the close voter thinks this is off-topic because it's about server/infrastructure administration

Comment: @DoNhuVy What about `docker run -u root ...` option. Does it work?

Comment: When I run `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 -u root -v /Users/donhuvy/Documents/oracle12c_data:/u01/app/oracle -e DBCA_TOTAL_MEMORY=2048 sath89/oracle-12c` I see `chown: changing ownership of '/u01/app/oracle': Operation not permitted`.

Comment: Have you considered raising this issue with [Maksym?](https://github.com/MaksymBilenko/docker-oracle-12c/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen)

Comment: I just ask him via email, and I am waiting.

Comment: Seemly this is the cause: https://support.apple.com/en-vn/HT204899 A solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32661637/3728901 but It is dangerous. I am looking for another solution.

Comment: See [**Running Oracle 12c EE in Docker container**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2017/12/29/docker-oracle-12c-ee-on-ol7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On macOS 10.13.1 High Sierra with Docker Community Edition version 17.09.1-ce-mac42 (21090) 3176a6af01, do these steps:

```
sudo docker pull sath89/oracle-12c
sudo mkdir -p /Users/donhuvy/Documents/oracle12c_data
sudo mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle
```

To avoid error

> chown: changing ownership of '/u01/app/oracle': Operation not
>   permitted

Use Finder, go to directory `/Users/donhuvy/Documents/oracle12c_data`, Right click, choose context menu ***Get info***, see at the bottom right corner, you will see a lock icon, click the icon, enter your administration password. Then set permission `Read & Write` for `everyone`

[image]

Do the same thing with directory `/u01/app/oracle`

Then run

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 -v /Users/donhuvy/Documents/oracle12c_data:/u01/app/oracle -e DBCA_TOTAL_MEMORY=2048 sath89/oracle-12c
```

After you worked, if you want pause/stop your work, turn off Docker. When you turn on Docker, return previous works, all things are still exist.