# Unable install gems from 'https ://rubygems.org/' after MacOS Mojave update SSL/TLS (?)

Tags: ssl, openssl, homebrew, rvm, macos-mojave

I am currently unable to install gems from 'https://rubygems.org/'
I recently updated to Mojave and updated and upgraded brew in order to get mysql running again.
Now I discovered that I am unable to install gems from rubygems.

When trying to install gem

```
[REPRO]$ gem install rdoc-data -v 3.12
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rdoc-data' (= 3.12), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I tried already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o), but it did not work.

Trying to update RVM

```
[REPRO]$ rvm get stable
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rvm/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer.asc
Verifying /Users/MYACCOUNT/.rvm/archives/rvm-installer.asc
gpg: Signatur vom Sat Mar 31 23:47:44 2018 CEST
...
GPG verified '/Users/MYACCOUNT/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.4.tgz'
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/MYACCOUNT/.rvm/
RVM PATH line found in /Users/MYACCOUNT/.mkshrc /Users/MYACCOUNT/.profile /Users/MYACCOUNT/.zshrc.
RVM PATH line not found for Bash, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.
RVM sourcing line found in /Users/MYACCOUNT/.profile /Users/MYACCOUNT/.bash_profile /Users/MYACCOUNT/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/MYACCOUNT/.rvm/ is complete.
  * RVM 1.30 simplifies behavior of 'rvm wrapper' subcommand


RVM reloaded!
```

Trying to update CERTs

```
[REPRO]$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
Selected SSL certs for: ruby-2.3.4
cURL certificate bundle /usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt not found
Updating certificates bundle /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Already up to date.
Updating certificates bundle /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Updating certificates bundle '/etc/openssl/cert.pem'
MYACCOUNT password required for 'command tee /etc/openssl/cert.pem': 
Updated.
Updating certificates bundle /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem: Updating certificates bundle '/System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem'
tee: /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem: Operation not permitted
Failed.
Updating certificates bundle /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem: Updating certificates bundle '/System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem'
tee: /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem: Operation not permitted
Failed.
Updating certificates bundle /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem: Already up to date.
```

Trying to update RVM

```
[REPRO]$ rvm rubygems latest
Installed rubygems 2.6.8 is newer than 2.0.17 provided with installed ruby, skipping installation, use --force to force installation.
```

Trying to install gem

```
[REPRO]$ gem install rdoc-data -v 3.12
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rdoc-data' (= 3.12), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I have two openssl installed through brew:

```
[REPRO]$ brew info openssl
openssl: stable 1.0.2p (bottled) [keg-only]
SSL/TLS cryptography library
https://openssl.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_1 (1,791 files, 12.3MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-04-17 at 00:25:36
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2 (1,792 files, 12.3MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-06-22 at 06:37:09
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2p (1,793 files, 12MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-09-25 at 07:30:55
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/openssl.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: makedepend ✘
==> Options
--without-test
    Skip build-time tests (not recommended)
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the SystemRoots
keychain. To add additional certificates (e.g. the certificates added in
the System keychain), place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

openssl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries.

If you need to have openssl first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openssl you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Analytics
install: 556,733 (30d), 1,491,119 (90d), 4,803,757 (365d)
install_on_request: 75,928 (30d), 212,774 (90d), 546,010 (365d)
build_error: 14,735 (30d)
```

and

```
[REPRO]$ brew info openssl@1.1
openssl@1.1: stable 1.1.1 (bottled) [keg-only]
Cryptography and SSL/TLS Toolkit
https://openssl.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.0h (6,587 files, 15.6MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-04-17 at 00:24:57
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1 (7,821 files, 17.9MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-09-25 at 07:31:15
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/openssl@1.1.rb
==> Options
--without-test
Skip build-time tests (not recommended)
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/c_rehash

openssl@1.1 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Analytics
install: 0 (30d), 0 (90d), 0 (365d)
install_on_request: 0 (30d), 0 (90d), 0 (365d)
build_error: 13 (30d)
```

I have 'PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' in my ~/.bash_profile

Everything used to work before the system update, but now my dev system is broken. Can anyone help? I can set http;//rubygems.org in gem file and therefore install gems through bundle install, but this is no solution.

Update:

I found out some more details: on a second machine everything is working as it is supposed to. On both systems RVM relies on openssl, which in both cases is brew/openssl or brew/openssl@1.1. On the first machine I get:

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
Selected SSL certs for: ruby-2.3.4
cURL certificate bundle /usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt not found
Certificates bundle /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem is up to date.
Certificates bundle /etc/openssl/cert.pem is up to date.
Certificates bundle /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem is old.
Certificates bundle /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem is up to date.
```

on the second I get:

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
Selected SSL certs for: ruby-1.8.7-head
cURL certificate bundle /usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt not found
Certificates bundle /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem is up to date.
```

Why does does the first machine check also in /System/Library/? How can I configure it to not do so?

Comment: Can you run `rvm --trace osx-ssl-certs update all` and post content ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried and got 7000 lines of code. What part of it do you need?

Comment: It appears the rubygems.org server is down!

Comment: If you can post the whole trace or maybe on third party website like pastebin because it's hard to tell which part i need but normally it's in the end. (rubygems seems having hard time yeah)

Comment: I had to create 2 files: https://pastebin.com/u/SEJU/1/0/1/?guest=1

Comment: http://uptime.rubygems.org/

Comment: Ok, it seems rvm (as root) can't write new cert in `/System/Library/OpenSSL/` as seen in this error `tee: /System/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem: Operation not permitted`, i think it's the result of macOS System Integrity Protection, maybe try to disable it (just for rvm updating cert) as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled
If that work you should open an issue on rvm github.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk thanks Pavel! When I was checking a hour ago rubygems.org showed everything online ... maybe this part was not running too....

Comment: I upgraded a second machine to Mojave and there I am able to install from rubygems. How can I troubleshoot the first machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install gems. I had to recompile all rubies:

```
$ ram uninstall ruby-1.8.7-p374
$ rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p374 --with-gcc=clang
$ rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p374@openssl-test01 --create
$ gem install rdoc-data -v 3.12
```

After this I was able to install although the link to /System/openssl is still shown in rvm osx-ssl-certs status all.