# badblocks: Resource busy while trying to determine device size

Tags: unix, terminal

I am trying to run bad blocks on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I installed bad blocks using macports. I keep encountering errors when attempting to run it and I am not sure how to even get bad blocks running

```
sudo badblocks -c 4096 -s -w -o /Users/mcbeav/Desktop/blocks.txt /dev/disk0s2
```

This keeps returning the error

**badblocks: Resource busy while trying to determine device size**

If I try

```
sudo badblocks -c 4096 -s -w -o /Users/mcbeav/Desktop/blocks.txt /dev/disk0
```

I get the error

**badblocks: Value too large to be stored in data type invalid end block (7813820416): must be 32-bit value**

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Can you try the second command without -c option? What is the size of /dev/disk0?

Comment: You might be able to circumvent MacOS preventing writes to the disk, by using the non-destructive read-write mode (-n instead of -w).

Comment: @amol it’s an 8TB drive. I’ll give it a try without the -c flag when I get a moment. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @gregory I could give it a try and see what happens, but my intensions are to basically burn in the disk to see if it’s going to fail. It’s brand new, and because of the circumstances I won’t get into, I’d like to run badblocks writing each sector of the disk with random bits and then stress test it using bonnie++

Comment: @mcbeav, Ok; well then I'd use diskutil to unmount the drive:  `diskutil unmount /Volumes/foo` and then try running badblocks.

Comment: @gregory I also did try this. In disk utility I just clicked the drive, clicked the unmount button, but then there was no disk to pass to the badblocks command. would I just pass it by using the volume's name like you specified /Volumes/volumeName ?

Comment: @mcbeav, are you saying this is the only drive you have? You're going to need a drive with OSX and drive/thumb drive for badblocks. If this isn't possible, I'd use a linux bootable drive to run it. See here for details: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57869/what-free-or-open-source-software-can-i-use-with-mac-hardware-to-verify-integrit

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is that you:

a) Run badblocks via the Mac OS X console in [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

High Sierra (10.13+) along with APFS (file format system) prevent certain operations on disk. You'll have to be in recovery mode or turn off disk protection to do as you propose.

```
Turn off your Mac (Apple > Shut Down).
Hold down Command-R and press the Power button. ...
Wait for OS X to boot into the OS X Utilities window.
Choose Utilities > Terminal.
Enter csrutil disable.
Enter reboot.
```

Mac OS X Workaround:

My sense from past experience is that you are hitting the MacOSX security features (Disk protection and app certification).

Booting to Ubuntu (USB Stick) and running the badblocks test that way is going to be easier. (In my opinion)

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I ran the csrutil disable command from recovery mode before I ever tried to run badblocks. I’ll have to try and run badblocks from recovery and see if that works

Comment: @mcbeav Can you share your Mac Machine version and disk setup? For example, are you using flash disks or rotating disks? My sense is that recovery mode will remove the risk of disk contention.

Comment: it's actually a "Hackintosh" So, I'm not sure exactly how much that information would help, but that really shouldn't affect much of anything. The 8TB is a WD Red NAS drive, connected via a SATA port. The OS boots from an SSD. I can boot into windows, but I don't have much experience using the linux terminal in windows now that it is apparently available?

Comment: You may want to review this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57869/what-free-or-open-source-software-can-i-use-with-mac-hardware-to-verify-integrit - for example, boot to Ubuntu and run badblocks from that OS on your disk. [Idea]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test anything out for a couple of days now. The post is a bit old, and some of the information is incorrect, however overall, I think I'm probably going to end up just booting Linux from a USB stick and running bad blocks like that. I don't really want to waste anymore time messing with it. I'm going to try whatever is suggested in the thread and if nothing works go for the Linux route.

Comment: @mcbeav - My sense from past experience is that you are hitting the MacOSX security features (Disk protection and app certification). Booting to Ubuntu (USB Stick) and running the badblocks test that way is going to be easier. (In my opinion)

Comment: this is probably what I will end up doing, Thanks for the advice and help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. But then I opened Disk Utility and pressed Eject on the physical device (make sure it's the hard drive and not the volume). This will unmount the volumes but will keep the device still available, which you can check by running:

```
diskutil list
```

Now run the badblocks command again and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get badblocks working for OSX 10.15 by

1) disabling csrutil, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32661637)

2) unmounting the badblock-desired drive via Disk Utility

3) running badblocks: `sudo badblocks -b 4096 -w -s -v "$MOUNT_POINT" > "badblocks.info"`, where `MOUNT_POINT=/dev/disk2`

---

I installed badblocks via `brew install e2fsprogs`, as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1366790)

---

Tangentially, I also did [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135565/how-do-i-get-detailed-smart-disk-information-on-os-x-mavericks-or-later#comment315402_135566) in order to query the USB-connected drive via smartctl.