# How to change java default directory in MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, java-8, java-16

Java is installed under `usr/bin/java` in my machine. Due to security reasons found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38435256/1601571), i'd like to set it to `usr/local/bin/java` so i can manipulate it when necessary. I'd like to understand how this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No clue. I use [`sdkman`](https://sdkman.io/).

Comment: Mysterious. "Manipulate"?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?